# libGDX - How to fill Table to Cell size?

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to make sub `Table` in a `Cell` to fill to that cell as a parent.

```
    // Main Table
    Table mainTable = new Table();

    // Sub Table
    Table subTable = new Table();

    mainTable.add(        ).expand().row(); // cell-1

    mainTable.add(subTable).expand().row(); // cell-2

    mainTable.add(        ).expand().row(); // cell-3
```

**The Code result:**

[image]

**When** I make `subTable.setFillParent(true)`, it will fill to `mainTable`. Ok its well.

[image]

**But** I want to make `subTable` fill to expand size of the `cell-2`.

**I mean:**

[image]

**How can I make this?**

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#fill

Comment: @Arctic45 Yes, you are right. `mainTable.add(subTable).fill().expand().row();.
Post your answer to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check LibGDX wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#fill

> The fill method causes a widget to be sized to the cell. Like expand,
>   there are also fillX and fillY methods.
>
> ```
> table.add(nameLabel).expand().bottom().fillX();
> ```
>
> ...